# How to populate DataGridComboBoxColumn from property List<T> located inside of ObservableCollection<T>? MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid, datagridcomboboxcolumn

I have a property ObservableCollection SomeEmployee in my view model class:

```
private ObservableCollection<Employee> someEmployee=new ObservableCollection<Employee>();
public ObservableCollection<Employee> SomeEmployee 
{
 get {return someEmployee;}
  set { 
       someEmployee=value;
       OnPropertyChanged("SomeEmployee");
}
```

SomeEmployee is populated by PopulateObject() method

```
public static IEnumerable<Employee> PopulateObject()
    {
        IEnumerable<Employee> list = new List<Employee>() 
        {
             new Employee { EmployeeName = "Bob", EmployeeID=1,
                  ListOfEmployees=new List<Employee>(){
                      new Employee(){EmployeeName="Gigi"}, 
                      new Employee(){EmployeeName="Bacconi"} 
                      new Employee(){EmployeeName="Teodor"} }
                          },
             new Employee { EmployeeName = "John", EmployeeID=2, },
             new Employee { EmployeeName = "Adam", EmployeeID=3, }, 
        };
        return list;
    }
```

And Employee class has a property ListOfEmployees which I would like to show in DataGridComboBoxColumn of DataGrid:

```
public class Employee 
{
   public int? EmployeeID {get; set;}
   public string EmployeeName {get; set;}
   public List<Employee> ListOfEmployees {get; set;}
```

And my DataGrid:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{SomeEmployee}">
 <DataGrid.Columns>
     <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="ComboBox" SelectedItemBinding="{Binding EmployeeName}">
      <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
  <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
     <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="Binding Path=DataContext.ListOfEmployees}"/>
  </Style>
   </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
  </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
   </DataGrid.Columns>
   </DataGrid>
```

However, at first ComboBox is not shown, it is just like simple DataGridTextColumn is shown. At second, there is no data in the cell.

**How to populate DataGridComboBoxColumn from property List located inside of ObservableCollection**?What am I doing wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to set ItemsSource in style, you can do something like:

```
 <DataGrid ItemsSource="{SomeEmployee}">
   <DataGrid.Columns>
     <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="ComboBox" SelectedItemBinding=" {Binding EmployeeName}" ItemSource="{Binding EmployeeID}">
     </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
   </DataGrid.Columns>
 </DataGrid>
```

`ListOfEmployees` doesn't exists in your Model, I suppose you want to bind to `EmployeeID`

Comment: Is your grid in readonly mode? You have to go in edit mode so the combobox can show.

Comment: I've tried all variants IsReadOnly="True" and IsReadOnly="False". However, there is no combobox.

Comment: I used your code in my test app and it works fine. If you click TWO times in the cell the combobox will show. Sorry i cannot help further.